# How do I make a clickable button run a subprugram? Python 3.X.X

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hey everyone I have a minor setback with my python code, I have used the tkinter import to create a GUI for a project that has worked fine but when I code for the button to run a subprogram it notifies me of a syntax error that I can't figure out how to resolve, the error appears on the 'def' in "def coinCount"  if anyone can help me id much appreciate it. I have attached my code for the GUI menu below. Thanks in advance

```
#Create Menubar in Python GUI Application  
import tkinter as tk  
from tkinter import ttk  
from tkinter import Menu  
win = tk.Tk()  
win.title("Coin Counter 3000")  
#Exit action  
def _quit():  
   win.quit()  
   win.destroy()  
   exit()  
#Create Menu Bar  
menuBar=Menu(win)  
win.config(menu=menuBar)  
#File Menu  

fileMenu= Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)  
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")

fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="1: Add to coincount-", command=lambda: def countCoint():  
fileMenu.add_separator()

fileMenu.add_command(label="2: View all records-", command=lambda: 
fileMenu.add_separator()

fileMenu.add_command(label="3: Accuracy of counters (volunteer accuracy report)-", command=lambda:def volunteerReport():
fileMenu.add_separator()

ileMenu.add_command(label="4: Display Totals-", command=lambda:def displayTotals():
fileMenu.add_separator()

sub_menu = Menu(fileMenu, tearoff=0)
sub_menu.add_command(label='Keyboard Shortcuts')
sub_menu.add_command(label='Color Themes')


fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="4: Show total-", command=lambda:def runningTotals():  
fileMenu.add_separator()

fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)  
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)  
#Help Menu  
helpMenu= Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)  
helpMenu.add_command(label="About")
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)  
#Calling Main()  
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues.

First, you must define your functions (what you call "subprograms") before passing them as a parameter to `add_command`.

Second, you are misusing `lambda` by attempting to define a named function with it. `lambda`s are used to create **small, anonymous** functions, so the `def` keyword is not necessary and causing syntax errors. See Python's [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) and other resources online on its usage.

Third, a lambda may not be the best tool for the job here. Instead, fully define the functions you plan to use (`coinCount`, `runningTotals`, etc.) and pass the function *names* as parameters.

```
def addToCoinCount():
    # Your code.

fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="1: Add to coincount-", command=addToCoinCount
fileMenu.add_separator()
```

Comment: Ahh ok thank you, i have to be honest I am just learning python in school and am a novice and have no clue really what I am doing I just take bits of other code and try piece them together.

Comment: To get the most out of your class, it's best to take the time to look at the code you have and understand what you're telling the computer. Start with a small and manageable problem and get to a point where you understand how to solve it, then move onwards. Slapping code together may work, but it's error prone and definitely not a lot of fun to create!

Comment: I attempted your improved method i have overcome the syntax on def but a new syntax on "fileMenu.add_separator()" has occurred, 
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="1: Add to coincount-", command=countCoins 
fileMenu.add_separator()

Comment: Missing closing `)` at the line `fileMenu.add_command(...`.